# Inject all properties from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer into a bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` that loads multiple properties files. I want to inject the merged properties map into a Spring Bean via config XML.

Can I do that and how?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?63220-How-to-get-merged-properties-from-PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer). I don't believe such a merged map is available.

Comment: yep that worked - if you want to put it in as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, but you can +rep the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just create a properties bean and use that for your `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and your `Config` bean:

```
<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:default.properties</value>
      <value>classpath:someother.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="myProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="myConfigBean" class="my.pkg.Config">
    <constructor-arg ref="myProperties" />
</bean>
```

Comment: will that inject the *merged* properties into myConfigBean?

Comment: Err... why do I need the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer reference? I tried this without and it seemed to work fine.

Is it so the props are injected and available even outside the myConfigBean

Comment: Yes. Also the question mentioned the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.