# Inject Resolved Properties Object to Another Bean

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to inject a `java.util.Properties` object into another bean through XML config. I have tried the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17117878/1247445) without success, presumably because the bean is being injected before the property resolution occurs. Is there a way that I can force the `java.util.Properties` object to be resolved before being injected to my class?

Below is the trimmed/edited version of what I have. `PropertiesConsumingClass` does receive the merged, but unresolved properties of a, b, and c properties files.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="properties" ref="allProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="allProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="propertiesArray">
    <util:list>
      <util:properties location="classpath:a.properties" />
      <util:properties location="classpath:b.properties" />
      <util:properties location="classpath:c.properties" />
    </util:list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean class="PropertiesConsumingClass">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="allProperties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because what Spring calls a property isn't the same thing as what Java calls a property. Basically, a Spring property lives in a `<property>` tag, and this is what gets resolved by `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. You can also use property placeholders inside `@Value` annotations. Either way you have a string with `${}` placeholders that get resolved, possibly the string is converted to the correct type, and injected into your bean.

`java.util.Properties` are used to resolve placeholders in Spring properties, but they aren't considered for resolution themselves. Any properties in `a.`, `b.`, or `c.properties` will be substituted into Spring property placeholders, but `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't know or care if the values it gets from those files have `${}` in them.

Now, [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) does resolve placeholders inside its config files, but it has special sauce to accomplish that. It's also a very opinionated library that wants to control your app's lifecycle and does lots of magical things behind the scenes, so it's very hard to adopt or drop except at the very beginning of a project.